# Java script how to write an if condition passed to a $.modal()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have wrote a method like this and i want to include a condition inside the string passed to the model and my method did not work . How to include an if condition?

```
$.modal("<div id='edit_user_form' class='user_mange_popup' align='center'>/'if(true){//do   something}'/</div>")
```

Comment: elaborate on what you are trying to do. Seems would make more sense to add an options argument to your $.modal method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "<div id='edit_user_form' class='user_mange_popup' align='center'>"
if (true){
  a += something
  }
a += </div>
$.modal(a)
```

dOes this solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to vary the content of the string depending on some condition you can do something like this:

```
var modalStr = "<div id='edit_user_form' class='user_mange_popup' align='center'>";
if(yourConditionHere){
   modalStr += "some other string to add";
}
modalStr += "</div>";

$.modal(modalStr);
```

Obviously you can add an `else` or as many `else if` branches as you like, and concatenate in variables, etc.

Or you can use the ternary conditional operator:

```
$.modal("<div id='edit_user_form' class='user_mange_popup' align='center'>"
        + (someCondition ? "string to add if true" : "string to add if false")
        + "</div>");
```

Comment: no .$.modal() renders a pop up window and i want to modify the html to be passed as a string using if condition

Comment: That's exactly what both options in my answer do. If that isn't meeting your needs for some reason please update your question to show the string you are starting with and the string you want to end up with.